# Spy on LCD screen with Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware

I have this [digital crane scale](https://canadianbestseller.com/pd/outmate-mini-digital-crane-scale-300kg-600lbs-with-led-aluminium-alloy-shellorange/?v=3e8d115eb4b3#gsc.tab=0). It has a 5 digit 7 segment LCD display. My objective is to be able to read what is displayed on the LCD display with a Raspberry Pi. This is what the PCB looks like: [image: crane scale PCB]
It looks like there are 15 input pins to the LCD module at the top of the PCB. Could I read some of these with the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi to determine what is being displayed on the screen?

Comment: AFAIK the GPIO pins can only be used if the voltage is 3.3V. First make sure the scale does not use higher voltage on that connections, otherwise you may fry your Raspberry GPIO pins.

Comment: You might be able to after verifying that the voltages are in the correct range, but you'll need to guess the baud rate if it is using a serial protocol. If you have access to a logic analyzer (even a small hobbyist one), that would help you with this task.

Comment: Not bad, but could use some clarifying information.